# UIPickerView selection input Swift 4 or 5

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` that selects from an array of states and the last item in the array is “outside the US”. When the last item in the array is selected I want to show another input option for country.

Currently I have the country input set to hidden in `viewDidLoad`.

This is my attempt at trying to get this to work, but it keeps causing a crash on selection of the last item.

```
var stateOptionsList = ["", "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District Of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming", "Outside The United States"]

let outsideOfUS = stateOptionsList[statePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 52)] as String

print(outsideOfUS)

if selectStateInput.text == outsideOfUS {
    countryContainer.isHidden = false
} else {
    countryContainer.isHidden = true
}
```

I put the let `outsideOfUs` var in the pickerView `didSelectRow`. Not sure if this is where I am supposed to put this.

Comment: Your picker only has 1 component, not 53 or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using:

```
selectedRow(inComponent: 52)
```

So, it undoubtedly crashed with an error message like:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 52 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

When it crashes, it often provides useful messages like this. This message is telling us that the picker has only one component. There is no component number 52.

So, instead, just grab the item directly from your model object:

```
let outsideOfUS = stateOptionsList[52]
```

Or, so you don’t have to change this if you later add other US territories, like Puerto Rico, just grab the last one from your list, e.g.

```
guard let outsideOfUS = stateOptionsList.last else { return }
```

Comment: I dont know how I messed that up. Thanks for explaining inComponent as I was obviously confused.